# How do I remove the space to the right of my nav bar?

Tags: html, css, nav

New to html and css, I have checked other questions here and googled it but I am not finding an answer.

I am working on the nav bar and have this annoying space I can not figure out how to get rid of.

I made the background of the nav element blue so you can see what I am referring to and here is a screenshot:

http://imgur.com/v18HTjH

The HTML is:

```
<div class="topnavbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-element"><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-element"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-element"><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-element"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li class="nav-element"><a href="#testimonials">testimonials</a></li>
    <li class="nav-element"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.topnavbar{
  background-color: blue;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:90%;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius:30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
}   

body {
  top:1px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #FA0000;
}
```

Comment: You have them floated left with a width of 150px (from the a), you could try inline-block with text-align center instead

Comment: Do you have a live page?

Comment: No I do not have a live page.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesnt necessarily take away the space, but it centers the links within the navbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/261/

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center; /* added */
}

li {
  /* float: left; */ /* commented out */
  display: inline-block; /* added */
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

remove width attribute  .topnavBar in CSS file and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Add width:150px; to the li class,
and change width of .topnavbar to 67%;

Actually you are giving width 90% to .topnavbar but your content of all li's is just 67%.

Comment: yeah the width percentage was the problem, was ~73% not 67% but it is fixed now.

Comment: edit: I am an idiot, I see now that it depends on your window size on whether it splits into more then 1 line. So for you it is probably 67%...